# Rails Model Visible Everywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a rails application with one model that I want to show a loop of in the footer which appears on every page.

In the the Variety Model

```
class Variety < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
end
```

I have found that adding:

```
@varieties = Variety.all
```

to every view works but i am sure this is bad practice.

Comment: You can add whatever you want to show on each view within the `layouts/application.htm.erb` file.

Comment: If it's located in a separate section, like a footer, you can create a partial for that footer. Also It is not a good practice to make database requests in the view. You can create a `before_action` in your application_controller.rb file and fetch the desired data there. This action will be triggered every time a controller is called, so you write it only once. (Also I assume your Variety model has only a few records, like categories... )

Comment: so like devise uses authenticate_user @Maxence? should it be a helper or application_controller?

Comment: @JoeBloggs In application controller.

Comment: @JoeBloggs yes you can add a `before_action` in the application controller. This controller is application wise. This is where I put my hooks for cookie advertisement etc .. It is triggered before every other controller action. So if you need something to happen in all your controllers, just put it there. You cannot really use a helper, because a helper is scoped to the views and it is bad practice to fetch data from the database in the view. It is better to do that in a controller.

Comment: What sebastian suggest with `layouts/application.html.erb` is exactly what I suggest above with `controllers/application_controller.rb`. Both these files for their very type ( view and controller) happen globally. Both are triggered before any child (one specific view or one specific controller action). Then in `layouts/application.html.erb` you can use the data (`@varieties`) that you have fetched in `controllers/application_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this case, it's better to do something like this, in your application controller, you add a before action, so on every action, independent of the controller you are looking for, it will fill the instance variable

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :fill_varieties

  private

  def fill_varieties
    @varieties = Variety.all
  end

end
```

and then after this, create a partial on views/layouts/_footer.html.erb

```
<ul>
  <% @varieties.each do |variety| %>
    <li><%= variety.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

of course you need to change the view with the code about how you want to show it.

and on your views/layouts/application.html.erb just call the partial

```
<%= render "layouts/footer" %>
```

and it will render on every request